# matlab creating nonlinear model fit: two independent variables linear and non

Tags: matlab, model

I am trying to fit a nonlinear regression model with two predictor variables. I am having trouble writing my model.

z = dependent variable 
x = independent variable with relationship to z defined: `a*tanh(-b*x/a)+c`

y relationship to z is linear. But only linear because of the range of my data

here is what I have thus far:

```
a*tanh(-b*x/a)+c + (d*y)
```

Ideally I would like to have a 3rd categorical independent variable, which could be numerically represented with a 0 or 1

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, but take a look at Matlab's curve fitting toolbox `cftool` if you have access to it. It allows you to fit custom equations, amongst other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Matlab documentation for [`fitnlm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitnlm.html), their most rounded and mainstream tool for non-linear regression analysis. It was introduced in 2013b. The older function is [`nlinfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nlinfit.html).

One way to use it is, from docs linked above

```
mdl = fitnlm(X, y, modelfun, beta0)
```

Here `X = [x1, x2]` is a matrix built with vectors `x1` and `x2`, that contain data for your predictors (your `x` and `y`).  The `y` above is the vector with data for the response (your `z`). The `modelfun` is where you provide the functional dependence.  This can be done in two ways, and below I use simpler "*string syntax*".  In your case of `z = a*tanh(-b*x/a)+c + (d*y)`, the modeling function is

```
modelfun = `y~(b1*tanh(-b2*x1/b1)+b3+b4*x2)`
```

Note that this is the exact syntax, `'y~(...)'`. See "*Specify Nonlinear Regression Using Model String Syntax*" under "*Examples*" on the `fitnlm` page linked above.

Finally, `beta0` is the vector with initial values for the unknown coefficients.  (Getting reasonable values for that is quite critical for successful modeling.)
So your coefficients to be determined are `(b1, b2, b3, b4)`, and the vector `beta0` should have initial values for them, to start the fitting with.

Then, given that you have built `X = [x1, x2]` matrix with your data and chose values for `beta0`,

```
modfun = 'y~(b1*tanh(-b2*x1/b1)+b3+b4*x2)';
nlm =  fitnlm(X, y, modfun, beta0);
display(nlm);
```

This should show you fitted values for the coefficients and some statistics.

Useful pages could be on [non-linear regression](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nonlinear-regression-1.html) and this [overview](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/nonlinear-regression.html) with links to resources.

Comment: Thanks, I'll dive into the fitlm function!

Comment: I have gone ahead and skipped the addition of a categorical variable as it does not seem like an option for the nonlinearmodel fit. So, I just have two nonlinear models (two data sets) which works just fine. I can at least compare the two visually by plotting on over the other.

Comment: Thanks so much for the follow-up. I think I have already gotten there though. I created a function handle for 'modelfun' : 'modelfunj = @(b,xj)b(1).*tanh((b(2).*xj(:,1))./360)+b(3) +b(4).*(xj(:,2));' This seems to work perfectly. I will, however, use compare with your syntax. Thanks again.

Comment: @CMil  Nice :)  I used the string syntax just to keep it simpler. (It's no better, to say the least.)  Again, sorry for the unsuitable original post.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states that fitnlm is not usable for categorical data

[fitnlm reference](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/nonlinear-regression-1.html)